# Pandas select rows that contains both values (inclusive)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to select only rows that have both values.

For example, I am trying to select only a Patient who has **both** Right and Left on Ear column.

In this case, it would be only **Lisa**.

Here is code that I was trying to get the right data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Lisa', 'Lisa', 'Mac', 'Intosh'],
    'ear': ['Right','Left','Right','Left']
   }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'ear'])
df.loc[(df['name'] == 'Right') & (df['ear'] == 'Left')]
df
```

[image]

The code retrives everyone, but I am trying to only get row 0 and 1 because Lisa has **both** Right and Left for ear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution actually requires the use of `groupby` and `nunique`:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['ear'].transform('nunique') == df['ear'].nunique()]

   name    ear
0  Lisa  Right
1  Lisa   Left
```

You can simplify this assuming humans can only have two ears ;)

```
df[df.groupby('name')['ear'].transform('nunique').eq(2)]

   name    ear
0  Lisa  Right
1  Lisa   Left
```

---

**Details**
`groupby` will compute the number of (unique) ear entries with respect to the name:

```
df.groupby('name')['ear'].transform('nunique')

0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
Name: ear, dtype: int64
```

(The first two rows belong to Lisa.) The result is broadcasted to the original frame.

Then check what rows have a unique count of two and select accordingly.

Comment: That's a clever transform. Just to finalise the reduction after the transform (and to be pedantic) you'd need a df.name.unique().

Comment: @Will Assuming OP only wants the names of those with two ears (poor van gogh) and not the rows they are present in, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

I am using `filter`

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['Right','Left']).isin(x['ear']).all())
Out[106]: 
   name    ear
0  Lisa  Right
1  Lisa   Left
```

Or `issubset`

```
df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x : {'Right','Left'}.issubset(x['ear'].tolist()))
```

To fix your code need `isin` (get intersection of two series)

```
s1=df.loc[df.ear=='Right','name']
s2=df.loc[df.ear=='Left','name']
df.loc[df.name.isin(s1[s1.isin(s2)]),]
Out[119]: 
   name    ear
0  Lisa  Right
1  Lisa   Left
```