# Select row only that contain specific value with correlation to another column and group them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have this kind of dataframe and i want to select only these websites that have TLSVersion1.2 and 1.3 ONLY.
There is already a similar thing [Pandas select rows that contains both values (inclusive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156866/pandas-select-rows-that-contains-both-values-inclusive)

```
      websiteName TLSVersion    strength  kex_info  \
1     website1.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 2048   
2     website1.lt    TLSv1.3        A     rsa 2048  
 
3     website2.lt    TLSv1.0        C     rsa 2048   
4     website2.lt    TLSv1.1        A     rsa 2048   
5     website2.lt    TLSv1.2        A     rsa 2048   
6     website2.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519   

7     website3.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096   
8     website3.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096   
9     website3.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096   
10    website3.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519   

11    website4.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096   
12    website4.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096   
13    website4.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096   
14    website4.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
```

Desire Output
1: website1.lt  : True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using isin():

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'websiteName' : ['website1.lt']*2+['website2.lt']*4+['website3.lt']*4+['website4.lt']*4,
    'TLSVersion' : ['TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3', 'TLSv1.0', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3', 'TLSv1.0', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3', 'TLSv1.0', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'],
    'strength' : ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'kex_info' : ['dh 2048', 'rsa 2048', 'rsa 2048', 'rsa 2048', 'rsa 2048', 'ecdh_x25519', 'dh 4096', 'dh 4096', 'dh 4096', 'ecdh_x25519', 'dh 4096', 'dh 4096', 'dh 4096', 'ecdh_x25519']
})
print(f"Sample input dataframe:\n{df}")
df2 = df[df.TLSVersion.isin(['TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'])]
print(f"\nOutput with rows containing 1.2 and 1.3 only:\n{df2}")
```

Output

```
Sample input dataframe:
    websiteName TLSVersion strength     kex_info
0   website1.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 2048
1   website1.lt    TLSv1.3        A     rsa 2048
2   website2.lt    TLSv1.0        C     rsa 2048
3   website2.lt    TLSv1.1        A     rsa 2048
4   website2.lt    TLSv1.2        A     rsa 2048
5   website2.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
6   website3.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096
7   website3.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096
8   website3.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
9   website3.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
10  website4.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096
11  website4.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096
12  website4.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
13  website4.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519

Output with rows containing 1.2 and 1.3 only:
    websiteName TLSVersion strength     kex_info
0   website1.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 2048
1   website1.lt    TLSv1.3        A     rsa 2048
4   website2.lt    TLSv1.2        A     rsa 2048
5   website2.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
8   website3.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
9   website3.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
12  website4.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
13  website4.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
```

**UPDATED:**
The question as clarified by OP is: How do I find websites that support one or more versions within a specified list ['TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'] and do not support any versions other than those in the list?

Here is code to do that:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'websiteName' : 'website1.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.2', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 2048'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website1.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.3', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'rsa 2048'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website2.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.0', 'strength' : 'C', 'kex_info' : 'rsa 2048'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website2.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.1', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'rsa 2048'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website2.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.2', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'rsa 2048'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website2.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.3', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'ecdh_x25519'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website3.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.0', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website3.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.1', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website3.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.2', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website3.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.3', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'ecdh_x25519'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website4.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.0', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website4.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.1', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website4.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.2', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'dh 4096'},
    {'websiteName' : 'website4.lt', 'TLSVersion' : 'TLSv1.3', 'strength' : 'A', 'kex_info' : 'ecdh_x25519'}
])
print(f"\nSample input dataframe:\n{df}")
supportedVersions = ["TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"]
L = df.groupby('websiteName').apply(
    lambda x: x.query(
        'TLSVersion not in @supportedVersions'
    )).index.get_level_values(0).unique().tolist()
print(f"\nList of websiteName values to exclude from the result:\n{L}")
df2 = df[~df['websiteName'].isin(L)]['websiteName'].unique()
print(f"\nList of websites that support"
    f" one or more versions in the list {supportedVersions}"
    f" and no versions that are not in the list:\n{df2}")
```

Output

```
Sample input dataframe:
    websiteName TLSVersion strength     kex_info
0   website1.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 2048
1   website1.lt    TLSv1.3        A     rsa 2048
2   website2.lt    TLSv1.0        C     rsa 2048
3   website2.lt    TLSv1.1        A     rsa 2048
4   website2.lt    TLSv1.2        A     rsa 2048
5   website2.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
6   website3.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096
7   website3.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096
8   website3.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
9   website3.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519
10  website4.lt    TLSv1.0        A      dh 4096
11  website4.lt    TLSv1.1        A      dh 4096
12  website4.lt    TLSv1.2        A      dh 4096
13  website4.lt    TLSv1.3        A  ecdh_x25519

List of websiteName values to exclude from the result:
['website2.lt', 'website3.lt', 'website4.lt']

List of websites that support one or more versions in the list ['TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'] and no versions that are not in the list:
['website1.lt']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer but like i mentioned i need to show only where websites contain  1.2 and 1.3 ONLY if they have 1.1 then website should not be printed

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my code does. Please take a look at my updated, adjusted to make the output a little clearer: first it prints the input dataframe to show what it's using, and then it prints the filtered dataframe with websites containing 1.2 and 1.3 only.

Comment: Okay let me try explaining differently,  so we have websites and they have supported versions, etc website1 supports (TLSv1.2 , TLSv1.3) , website2 supports (TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3) . We can see that website2 supports more protocols but we need only a website that has supports specifically for 1.2 and 1.3)  so the outcome should be website1 , not rows with tls1.2 as a column value

Comment: @Robert OK, thanks for that clarification. I have updated the answer again, please take a look. This should do what you're asking, or something very similar.

Comment: Did my updated answer get to the result you were looking for?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late confirmation, yes it works! Your solution is more compact.
Also question could you give some recommendations where i can learn lambda  and .queryimplementation

Comment: For `query()`, see [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), [eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) and [expression evaluation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval). For `lambda`, try [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and this [functional programming tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by dividing it into parts:
First, I merge all tlscolumns into one row   :

```
allVersionInCollumn = noDuplicates.groupby(['websiteName'])['TLSVersion'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

allVersionInCollumn result:

```
    websiteName     TLSVersion
0   website1        TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
1   website2        TLSv1.2
2   website3        TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
3   website4        TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
```

Then I used these commands to split the columns:

```
splitedTLS = allVersionInCollumn["TLSVersion"].str.split(",", n=0, expand=True) 
allVersionSplited = allVersionInCollumn.join(splitedTLS)
allVersionSplited = allVersionSplited.drop(columns="TLSVersion")
```

allVersionSplited.head(10)

```
    websiteName    0       1       2     3
0   website1    TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 None
1   website2    TLSv1.2 None    None    None
2   website3    TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3 None    None
```

Then I used following command to sort [Python pandas sort multiple columns based on their values and other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817774/python-pandas-sort-multiple-columns-based-on-their-values-and-other-rows/71817941#71817941)

```
allVersionSplited= (allVersionSplited
 .replace({'None': pd.NA})   # assuming 'None' strings
 .melt(id_vars='websiteName')
 .assign(TLS=lambda d: d['value'])
 .pivot_table(index='websiteName', columns='TLS', values='value', aggfunc='first')
 .reset_index()
)
```

Droping previous columns

```
allVersionSplited.drop(allVersionSplited.iloc[:, 1:5],inplace=True,axis=1)
```

allVersionSplited.head()

```
TLS websiteName     TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
0   website1        TLSv1.0 NaN     NaN     NaN
1   website2        NaN NaN     TLSv1.2 NaN
2   website3        NaN NaN     TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
```

Then removed those rows that didn't have tlv1.0 and tls1.0 support

```
refined =   allVersionSplited[allVersionSplited["TLSv1.0" ].isnull()] 
refined =   refined[refined["TLSv1.1"].isnull()] 
refined.head()

TLS websiteName  TLSv1.0  TLSv1.1   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
1   website2     NaN      NaN       TLSv1.2 NaN
2   website3     NaN      NaN       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
```

Lastly `refined.shape[0]`
gives :
2